# Looking for an RFC5816 token that does not use default hashing algorithm

Tags: timestamp

I'd like to test some code that should be compatible with both RFC5816 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5816.txt) as well as RFC3161 tokens. The problem is that all timestamping services that I found so far which serve RFC5816 tokens (which use id-smime-aa-signingCertificateV2 rather than id-smime-aa-signingCertificate to identify the signer) do not specify the hashAlgorithm in ESSCertIDv2 (which AFAICT means the algorithm defaults to id-sha256)

could anyone share an RFC5816 token that explicitely specifies the hashAlgorithm to be used in its ESSCertIDv2 attribute?